# T-SQL: Exclude rows with same values from table

Tags: t-sql

I think for most of you it's a simple question, but I'm stranded here... Maybe It's too late.

Lets say I have a table with column 1-10

I want to show all that 10 colums, but want wo exclude rows, that have the same values in column 1,3,5

I tried something like this but it dind't really work:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Immo].[dbo].[Maschinen]  AS M1

WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT DISTINCT  column1,column3,column5
FROM [Immo].[dbo].[Maschinen] AS M2
WHERE 1=1  
AND M1.column1=M2.column1
AND M1.column3=M2.column3   
AND M1.column5=M2.column5
```

would appreciate any help, thanks guys!

Comment: Tell us more about values in other columns (2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10). You can try to use a GROUP BY clause but without any information about other column there is no possibile to give a correct answer. For example, if there is ok to use a simple aggregation function like max, min or avg for other columns? Or mayby you wish to get only first occurence of this kind of "unique" row? If yes then what about sorting to decide which row is the first in a group?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE NOT ((col1=col3) AND (col3=col5));
```